# Requesting Permissions from Xamarin Android Service

Tags: android, xamarin

Using Xamarin Android, I need to be able to access location updates from within a service.
I have tried the native Android.LocationManager, Plugin.Geolocator, and Xamarin.Essentials.Geolocation, but none of them seem to provide location updates. 
If I do it inside an activity, it works fine, but I have a requirement to post location updates from a service which launches at boot time. 
Yeah, I know it's a "privacy violation" or whatever, but the app is only used on company devices for a specific internal use.
I saw somewhere that requesting permissions from a service "is tricky," so I know it's possible, but the guy didn't elaborate on how to do it.

Comment: If this is a single use device, just whitelist the app permissions in system settings, otherwise request the permission upon first use (via an Activity context) and then your app is fine when it receives a boot broadcast.

Comment: Unfortunately, the app is something that is installed by our clients via Google's Play Store. Permissions are established on the initial launch, so that's not the issue. I can't figure out how to get location information without having an activity running.

Comment: That is a different issue|question. Are you not getting the boot receiver broadcast? Service not being started? ....? And if the app is in the Store, it is not an internal app as other people can install it and it falls under the Store guidelines.